# Breaking .preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I use `preventDefault()`, I typically place it at the top of the event handler, like so:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // do stuff
});
```

Is there any harm in placing it at the bottom of the event handler, and doing stuff before you invoke `e.preventDefault()`?

Another way of phrasing this question: can you be sure that, by including `e.preventDefault()` *anywhere* within the event handler, you will never follow through - say, to the target on a link or the submission of a form?

I've set up a fiddle that you can play with here: http://jsfiddle.net/tuanderful/SMdrN/

Comment: See you have already played in the fiddle, does it seem any harm doing that. it will be valid untill it is directly available in the click function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as nothing goes wrong in the code, it doesn't matter where you call `preventDefault`.

If you put it first in the code, it will prevent the default action even if the script crashes further on.

If you put it last in the code, it will only prevent the default action if the script didn't crash anywhere on the way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. where you place the statement is irrelevant.

As long as `e.preventDefault()` is called within the handler the default action will not be triggered

Answer (score 1):

You can place it wherever you want, you can even call `e.preventDefault();` inside some if block, it doesn't change the behavior